# Import and Export Scenario Issue in acumatica

Tags: import, export, acumatica

I have created a import scenario to update Formula . It helps me to insert and as well as update existing Formula or New Formula.

I am facing one problem in this scenario as I tries to import a formula where I have multiple materials but I am using this multiple materials on single process step, it is importing only a single material on the same process step on which I have given multiple material and also it is updating the last material value.

> Eg:- I have 2 process step (101 and 102)  and I have given 5 materials on 102 process step. So it skips 4 materials and insert or update last material value in formula.

I have used line number and also perform several operation , commit check box, make visible line number on UI and made changes in code but nothing work.

Please any one has any suggestion or solution to how I can fix this .